# Pulseaudio integration with KDE is broken in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, kde

The system mixer in the applet area in my Kubuntu installation suddenly disappeared, and I can't raise the volume from a keyboard shortcut anymore, basicly the desktop has no integration with pulseaudio anymore, but pulseaudio is running fine, I can set it up via pavucontrol without any problems.

Turns out the packages responsible for pulseaudio integration are pulseaudio-module-gconf and plasma-pa (which is dependant from the first one). 
The problem is that if I i install them pulseaudio doesn't even start anymore, even if I comment the respective modules out of the default.pa file. and the only solution is doing a clean reinstall of everything involved, avoiding those packages.

It's like they can't work together anymore, even though they did once, before I did a first clean reinstall of pulseaudio to solve a problem with bluetooth audio outputs.

What could I try?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem as you. Uninstalling the KDE applet managing sound and reinstalling it solved my problem temporarily, though it came back after an update.

**Edit :**
Completely solved the bug. Apparently, it was a known bug hitting several users.

Found on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1728587/comments/3:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

and it works again !